# update table using dynamic prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to accomplish dynamic PDO prepared `UPDATE` statements using a customized array filled with `$_POST` data.
The array structure looks like this:

```
$data = array();
$data[00001] = array("description"=>"item1", "stock"=>"100");
$data[00002] = array("description"=>"item2", "thr_alert"=>"20");
```

The mysql columns have the same name as the array keys. The `'id'` is the main array key (00001, 00002, etc).

My first approach was the method described here: [php.net pdo execute()](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.execute.php#111823)

```
foreach($data as $itemId=>$value) {
    $keys = array_keys($value);
    $fields = '`'.implode('`, `',$keys).'`';
    $placeholder = substr(str_repeat('?,',count($keys)),0,-1);
    echo "INSERT INTO `baz`($fields) VALUES($placeholder)";
    print_r(array_values($value)); //values to fill up execute() later on
    echo "<br>";
}
unset($keys, $fields, $placeholder, $itemId, $value);
```

Nice approach but doesn't work, as this is designed for `INSERT` prepared statements and can't be used for `UPDATE` as the syntax should be `UPDATE foo SET bar = :bar/? WHERE id = :id/?`.

Second approach:

```
$out = "UPDATE `baz` SET ";
foreach($data as $itemId=>$value) {
    foreach($value as $column=>$foo) {
    }
    $out1 .= $column." = :$column, ";
    $out2 = "WHERE id = :id";

}
$output = $out.rtrim($out1, ", ")." ".$out2."<br>";

echo $output;
```

Output:

> UPDATE baz SET stock = :stock, description = :description WHERE id = :id

Notice that only the first array is displayed.

Any ideas on how to achive my goal ?

Comment: I can't fix your code but I can say that your first approach didn't work since INSERT can't use a WHERE clause https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html - `INSERT ... SELECT` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` do.

Comment: I know .. it was just to show what I've tried so far. I edited the post now so it's not confusing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

I had to `unset($out1);` after `$output` is written and execute the `$out1` line in the second foreach loop (see code below).

```
$out = "UPDATE `foo` SET ";
foreach($data as $itemId=>$value) {
    foreach($value as $column=>$foo) {
        $out1 .= $column." = :$column, ";
    }
    $out2 = "WHERE id = :id";

    $output .= $out.rtrim($out1, ", ")." ".$out2."<br>";
    unset($out1);
}

echo $output;
```

The next step will be to prepare the statement using `$db->prepare($output);` and pass the data to `$db->execute($data);`.
So to answer my own question - yes, dynamic prepared statements using one "global" array IS possible ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Move this line inside the second foreach loop

```
$out1 .= $column." = :$column, ";
```

But the result is awkward for the current data,since it will generate something like

```
...SET description = :description,description = :description....
```

Comment: exactly. moved it to the second loop. output now:
`UPDATE foo SET description = :description, stock = :stock WHERE id = :id`
`UPDATE foo SET description = :description, stock = :stock, description = :description, thr_alert = :thr_alert WHERE id = :id`